# Ignore spaces in substring SQL/Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, substring, substr, spaces

I'm trying to substring the last 3 digits from a column. Problem is, some of them have a random space at the end, which then only returns 2 of the 3 needed values from the column. Right now I have:

```
    SELECT substr(infovalue, -3)
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE INFOCODE = 555
```

How can I get my statement to ignore the space at the end?

thanks!

Comment: Does the space need to be there?

Comment: What RDBMS (Versions of trim may work here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are in Oracle. Apply an `rtrim` to remove all trailing spaces

```
SELECT substr(rtrim(infovalue), -3)
FROM TABLE
WHERE INFOCODE = 555
```

And please specify the vendor & product version for all your questions.

Comment: Awesome! This works...I will specify vendor and product from now on!